# Why does this trigger a force close on Android?

Tags: android

Why does this code trigger a force close in Android?

```
`score.setText(Integer.parseInt((String) score.getText())+1);`
```

`score` is a TextView, and I am simply increasing the number by 1. I have predefined a String resource to be the initial number in the score TextView.

I am quite frustrated.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but your tone is probably going to work against you here.  Consider replacing emphatics with specifics.

Comment: @harpo, why would you reply to this just to tell me to improve my tone. of course, i know that my tone is frustrated, so what? we aren't allowed to be frustrated? lol

Comment: It is a courtesy to new users to avert unhelpful habits.  Also, to find the cause of a force close, you need to use `logcat`.  I had the same frustration when I started with Android.  `"$ANDROID_SDK_DIR/platform-tools/adb" logcat -d yourApp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you should try breaking down your code so you can actually see what is going on with it.

Instead of

```
score.setText(Integer.parseInt((String) score.getText())+1);
```

try

```
String tmp = score.getText().toString();
int score;
score = Integer.parseInt(tmp) + 1;
score.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

EDIT: Upon further reading of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29), setText has several overloads, one of which DOES take an int, but it takes the int of a resource ID. My guess is that your score is not a valid resource ID, thus crashing your application.

```
public final void setText (int resid)
```

Oh and as far as the frequent FC's when beginning Android Dev, it happens to the best of us. The key is to learn WHY the FC's happen, and have a LOT of patience.

Comment: Can you explain further what u meant when u said "your score is not a valid resource ID"? Because when i looked at the stack trace or whatever, it said Resources$NotFound exception. @Jack

Comment: @user1017670 Android stores resources such that you can easily access them via R.layout.myresourceID or R.string.somestring in code > these translate to integer resource ID's and are generated when you build (from your XML files -> you know that @+id/somestring attribute you used?) - thats what it means by "resid" or "resource id". http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html is a must read.

Answer (score 0):

mostly u need to do this

```
score.setText(Integer.parseInt(score.getText().toString())+1);
```

coz.. getText() returns a Editable Object which cannot be parsed to Integer. So it give NumberFormat Exception.

AndMake sure to set TextView,s Text to an integer initially..

Answer (score 0):

`TextEdit.setText` takes a `CharSequence` as input.
You are supplying an integer through `Integer.parseInt((String) score.getText())+1`
See, if converting it back to string and using it in setText helps.

You can convert an integer to string using `Integer.toString`.

PS: I am new to java myself.
The compiler should have ideally caught this error.
It's possible java uses some implicit type conversions from string to int.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
score.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(score.getText().toString())+1));
```

as you can pass the integer value that's why getting force the application

Comment: it worked! I have no idea why though.... Because the setText method can take an int.... any ideas?

Comment: Please see my answer which points you too exactly why. It is because it is expecting a RESOURCE id integer, not a value to display integer.

Comment: @Jack, what do u mean RESOURCE id integer? I was simply passing a number. Could you elaborate (thanks for the help btw)

Comment: See comment on my answer above